# display data using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to display data without an alert box, but I don't know how to do that? After submitting the form, a success message has to displayed without using an alert box; it should display in normal text. I have added my script code and database code. Can anyone help me? I am a beginner to jQuery. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#validate_form').parsley();
        $('#validate_form').on('submit',function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            if($('#validate_form').parsley().isValid())
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"db.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:$(this).serialize(),

                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
                        $('#submit').val('submitting the value');
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#validate_form')[0].reset();
                        $('#validate_form').parsley().reset();
                        $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
                        $('#submit').val('submit');
                        alert(data);

                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

db.php

```
<?php

//action.php

sleep(2);

if(isset($_POST['first_name']))
{
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=onlineshop", "root", "");

 $data = array(
  ':first_name'  => $_POST['first_name'],
  ':last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
  ':email'   => $_POST['email'],
  ':password'   => $_POST['password']
 );

 $query = "
 INSERT INTO tbl_register 
 (first_name, last_name, email, password) 
 VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
 ";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);


 if($statement->execute($data))
 {

 echo 'Registration successfully completed';

 }


}

?>
```

Comment: Use a modal, display the data on the modal or in the console.log

Comment: can you edit my code

Answer (score 1):

Make `<span></Span>` or `<Div></Div>` wherever you want to display the normal text in your HTML.

give id to the span or div

```
<div id ="displayMessage"> </div> `
```

then do the changes in your code at the place of alert.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#validate_form').parsley();
        $('#validate_form').on('submit',function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            if($('#validate_form').parsley().isValid())
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"db.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:$(this).serialize(),

                    beforeSend:function(){
                        $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
                        $('#submit').val('submitting the value');
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#validate_form')[0].reset();
                        $('#validate_form').parsley().reset();
                        $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
                        $('#submit').val('submit');
                        $("#displayMessage").html(data);

                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is the most sensible way of doing it. This way you can style and position the message "window" (div) easily. If you're using Jquery UI you can also use .dialog() method pretty easily.

Comment: it works. <div id="message" claas="alert alert-info" align="center">
         
        </div> but class not work...i dont know why..just text only there..not alert info

Comment: i need to display with alert info class..is it possible?

Comment: the spelling of class is not correct, yes it is posssible

Comment: ohhh....it is workingg .....tq

Comment: @PrabhuRio okay approve this answer, so this topic can be closed.

Comment: bro one doubt? can i ask you?

Comment: sure, ask whatever

Comment: (isset($_POST['first_name'])) it works....but if i give - if(isset($_POST['submit'])) it does not work....i don't know how it works . can you explain?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="complete">  if you give any value to your submit button it will work. it checks the value of the input name submit is set or not set.

Comment: i cant understand

Comment: @PrabhuRio  isset() checks that the input have any value set or not.  check the different between isset() & empty() function. whereas empty checks the input should not be null,0,blank

Comment: just try use the input button of html I used for submit, it will work.